# What connection option is better, or are both equal?

Tags: pandas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When connecting to Snowflake from Python, I'm wondering what connection type is more efficient, especially when connecting for Pandas related work. The two options are the snowflake-python-connector and the odbc connector. Right now I'm using the ODBC connector, but if the regular connector is faster, definitely going to use that. Primary use case is data extraction and analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Prefer the pandas methods of the Python connector since they load results straight to a dataframe, since as you can see from this graphic from a Snowflake blogpost, it is fastest.

[image]

You should also prefer recent versions of the connector to ensure that you have a version that is using Apache Arrow (implemented Feb 2020)